# Ajax not working with Apache, but same code is working with Django development server

Tags: ajax, django, apache, centos6

We have a simple Ajax request that gets some table data. This method works just fine when we run it on Django development server. But when we run the same code on Apache, not even the alert before get is getting fired.
We have Centos 6, Python 2.7, Apache2. There is nothing in apache error log.

Any suggestions?

```
    function getStatus(){
        try{
            alert("Before GET...");
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: /timer/get_status/,  
                data: {'operater':'99'}
            })
            .done(function(response) {
                alert("Response: " + response);
            });
        }catch(err){
            alert("Error: " + err.message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: '/timer/get_status/' => url should be string.

Comment: @gachdavit thanks, so obvious yet we busted our heads for hours..

Comment: You are welcome. This was javascript related problem.